# Mongo $or query using both $exists and $eq

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a mongoose schema as follows:

```
const itemSchema = new Schema({
  category: { type: String, required: false },
  doSomething: { type: Boolean, required: false }
});

const Item = Mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
```

The query I'm trying to do is:

"Find documents where category is "some_category" and doSomething is either equal to false or is empty"

```
const query = {
  category: 'some_category',
  doSomething: { '$or': [{ '$eq': false }, { '$exists' : false }] }
};
Item.find(query);
```

However, the find is throwing an error:

```
Cast to Boolean failed for value "[ { '$eq': false }, { '$exists': false } ]" at path "doSomething" for model "Item"
```

I'm thinking it's something in the way I'm using the $or operator but I've spent a few hours fussing with it and am at a loss.
Queries that don't use the $or are working fine, with either $eq or $exists.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think those are valid expressions. Try this instead:

```
{
    category: 'some_category',
    $or: [
        { doSomething: { $exists: false } },
        { doSomething: false }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are 100% correct :-) 

I ended up thinking that as well right after posting